# Proving that functor category between two $\mathscr{U}$-categories is a $\mathscr{U}$-category

Tags: category-theory

I am using the definition of a categories where $\text{Ob}(C)$ is a set and $\text{Hom}_C(x,y)$ is a set for $x,y\in\text{Ob}(C)$.

> A category $C$ is said to be a $\mathscr{U}$-category, if
> $\text{Hom}_C(x,y)\in\mathscr{U}$ for all $x,y\in C$. Furthermore, $C$
> is called $\mathscr{U}$-small if it is a $\mathscr{U}$-category and, there exists $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\text{Ob}(C)\cong U$.

Fix a universe $\mathscr{U}$ and suppose $C,D$ are $\mathscr{U}$-categories. Moreover, assume $C$ is $\mathscr{U}$-small. I want to prove the claim that $\text{Func}(C,D)$ is a $\mathscr{U}$-category.

Let $F,G:C\rightarrow D$ be two functors. We have to show that $\text{Hom}_{\text{Func}(C,D)}(F,G)\in\mathscr{U}$. Clearly the morphism of functors between from $F$ to $G$ are a subset of $\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))$. So it is sufficient to show that this latter set is an element of $\mathscr{U}$.

We know that $\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\in\mathscr{U}$, for all $x\in C$. If it were the case that $\text{Ob}(C)\in\mathscr{U}$, then it would immediately follow that $\prod_{x\in \text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\in\mathscr{U}$. However, we only know $\text{ob}(C)$ is isomorphic to a set in $\mathscr{U}$. How can this be used to show that $\prod_{x\in \text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\in\mathscr{U}$?

**Edit:**

Let $u:U\rightarrow\text{Ob}(C)$ be the bijection whose existence we have assumed. From this we get a bijection
$$\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\cong\prod_{a\in U}\text{Hom}_D(F(u(a)),G(u(a)))\in\mathscr{U}.$$
This implies that $\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))$ is isomorphic to an element of $\mathscr{U}$. But we wanted to prove that $\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\in\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathscr{U}$-small looks wrong. What does it mean to say $x\cong u$? An object $x$ of $C$ is not necessarily a set, so in what sense can it be "isomorphic" to a set $u$? The usual definition would be that $\operatorname{Ob}(C)\in\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Is it correct now?

Comment: The first paragraph looks OK now, but in the last paragraph, you say "we only know that each object of $C$ is isomorphic to a set in $\mathscr{U}$", which still doesn't make sense. But you also say "If it were the case that $C\in\mathscr{U}$". If you mean "If it were the case that $\operatorname{Ob}(C)\in\mathscr{U}$" then you might find that your problems are solved!

Comment: @JeremyRickard I have now fixed that. If $u:U\rightarrow\text{Ob}(C)$ is the bijection in question (where $U\in\mathscr{U}$), then we get $\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))\cong\prod_{a\in U}\text{Hom}(F(u(a)),G(u(a)))$. But I don't see why this isomorphism implies that the set of morphisms from $F$ to $G$ is an element of $\mathscr{U}$. Maybe I'm thinking about it in the wrong way..

Comment: Well, you've now reduced it to showing that a product of elements of $\mathscr{U}$, indexed by an element of $\mathscr{U}$, is (isomorphic to) an element of $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Correct and this means that $\prod_{a\in U}\text{Hom}_D(F(u(a)),G(u(a)))\in\mathscr{U}$. But this shows that $\prod_{x\in\text{Ob}(C)}\text{Hom}_D(F(x),G(x))$ is isomorphic to an element of $\mathscr{U}$, whereas I wanted to show that it is an element of $\mathscr{U}$. I have to prove that $\text{Func}(C,D)$ is a $\mathscr{U}$-category and this requires that $\text{Hom}_{\text{Func}(C,D)}(F,G)\in\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: I hadn't noticed before, but in your definition of a $\mathscr{U}$ category and a $\mathscr{U}$-small category you require Hom-sets to be *actually in* $\mathscr{U}$, but only require $\operatorname{Ob}(C)$ to be *isomorphic to* an object of $\mathscr{U}$. The definitions I'm familiar with are "actually in" for both cases, but I think that if you're consistent either way, then there's no problem?

Comment: Yes I think you might be right. The definition I'm using is strange in this sense. Thanks for your help.